# MySQL calculate difference between derived column of same query

Tags: mysql

How to calculate the difference between derived fields of the same query?

Here is my SQL query:

```
select Empname, sum(monthly_net) as Net,
sum(monthly_gross) as Gross, 
(Net-Gross) as diff_amount * from emp_table;
```

Here I derive fields called **Net** and **Gross**, and I want the difference between those. Is that possible to calculate the difference between derived fields?

Answer (score 1):

Not directly ([you can't use aliases in the same query](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-alias.html)), but you could use

```
sum(monthly_net)-sum(monthly_gross) as diff_amount
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't use aliases in the same query and also put * in front of all other column you can't use `*` after any other `*` must be the first in Select as below:

```
SELECT *,
       Empname, 
       sum(monthly_net) as Net,
       sum(monthly_gross) as Gross, 
       sum(monthly_net)-sum(monthly_gross) as diff_amount
FROM emp_table;
```